Blue and Red game on $[0,1]$
The game's rules are as follows:
The game is played on the segment $[0,1]$. Blue and Red take alternating turns, starting with Blue, where each player chooses a point on the segment $[0,1]$ (which hasn't already been chosen by either player in an earlier turn) and colours it in their colour. After each player chooses $m$ points, the game is finished.
Let $0\le r_1<r_2<...<r_m\le 1$ be the red points after all $2m$ moves. For each $[0,r_1),(r_1,r_2),(r_2,r_3),...(r_{m-1},r_m),(r_m,1]$ we say it is blue if and only if it contains at least one blue point. Similarly, if $0\le b_1<b_2<...<b_m\le1$ are the blue points at the end of the game, for each $[0,b_1),(b_1,b_2),(b_2,b_3),...,(b_{m-1},b_m),(b_m,1]$ we say it is red if and only if it contains at least one red point.
Blue's score is the sum of lengths of blue segments, and Red's score is the sum of lengths of red segments. The player with a bigger score wins.
That was a mouthful. I think an example game will make it clearer. For example, with $m=3$, one possible game is

With the $3$ blue segments highlighted:

And with the $2$ red segments highlighted:

In this case, Blue's score is $0.9$ and Red's score is $0.65$, hence Blue wins.
Which player has a winning strategy?
For $m=1$, Blue has a winning strategy. They can choose $\frac{1}{2}$ as their first move. Then, without loss of generality, red chooses $\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$. The game is finished, and the sum of blue segments is $\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$, whereas the sum of red segments is $\frac{1}{2}$, so Blue wins.
My guess is that Blue always has a winning strategy. I'm excited to see your insights
Edit: An alternative game similar to this one is the discrete case. More specifically, a game played on the set $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$. The rules are analogous, with the only difference being in the way we calculate the score. If $1\le r_1<r_2<...<r_m\le n$ are the red points at the end, we say that each set $\{r_{i-1}+1, r_{i-1}+2, ..., r_{i}-1\}$ is blue if and only if it contains at least one blue point. We define red set similarly. The score is the sum of cardinalities of blue and red sets respectively.
I was able to brute-force this game using a python script. The results seem to suggest that Blue wins if $m=1$ and $n$ is odd (this can be proven by a similar strategy as the $m=1$ continuous case, since the set has a middle element,) and the game ends in a draw otherwise. I'm not sure how applicable these results are to the continuous case, since we ommit the density property of the real numbers, i.e. we can't always choose a point between two existing points.

In the similar game played on a circle, Red can always force a draw by making sure the colors alternate. But I believe Red can also force a win. If so, then Blue's advantage on the interval is the interval ends, which are not picked up by either player. If Blue always has a winning strategy, it is to make one Red miss a larger interval end than he misses.

Why is (0.6, 0.7) in the example a $red$ interval? It contains no red points.

@blueslimr $(0.5,0.9)$ is a red interval because it is the interval between consecutive blue points and contains red points.

Ah, sure got it. Thank you!

It seems to be quite a tough problem. No way to break it down into sub-problems, formulate a strategy-stealing argument, etc. My intuition so far is that for $n$ odd: if $m$ odd then blue has a winning strategy, and if $m$ even, then blue can draw but neither player has a winning strategy.

Let's observe the $m=2$ case. We will denote by $b_i, r_i$ Blue's and Red's $i$-th move respectively. Let $B, R$ be their scores at the end of the game.
We claim that Red has a winning strategy.
If $b_1<\frac{1}{4},$ let $r_1=\frac{1}{4}.$

If $b_2<b_1,$ let $r_2=\frac{3}{4}.$ $B=\frac{1}{4}<1-b_1=R$
If $b_1<b_2<\frac{1}{4},$ let $r_2=\frac{3}{4}.$ $B=\frac{1}{4}<1-b_2=R$
If $\frac{1}{4}<b_2\le \frac{3}{4},$ then $b_2\le\frac{3}{4}<1-b_1,$ hence we can choose some  $b_2<r_2<1-b_1.$ $B=r_2<1-b_1=R$
If $\frac{3}{4}<b_2,$ let $r_2=\frac{3}{4}.$ $B=\frac{1}{2}<b_2-b_1=R$

If $\frac{1}{4}\le b_1<\frac{1}{2},$ let $r_1=1-b_1.$

If $b_2<b_1,$ let $r_2=\frac{1}{2}.$ $B=\frac{1}{2}<1-b_1=R$
If $b_1<b_2<r_1,$ then $3b_1-b_2>3b_1-r_2=4b_1-1\ge 0,$ i.e. $b_2-2b_1<b_1,$ hence we can choose some $b_2-2b_1<r_2<b_1.$ $B=1-b_1-r_2<1+b_1-b_2=R$
If $r_1<b_2$, then $1-b_2<1-r_1=b_1,$ hence we can choose some $1-b_2<r_2<b_1.$ $B=1-r_2<b_2=R$

If $b_1=\frac{1}{2},$ let $r_1=\frac{1}{4}.$

If $b_2<\frac{1}{4},$ let $r_2=\frac{3}{4}.$ $B=\frac{3}{4}<1-b_2=R$
If $\frac{1}{4}<b_2<\frac{1}{2},$ let $r_2=\frac{3}{4}.$ $B=\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{2}+b_2=R$
If $\frac{1}{2}<b_2\le \frac{3}{4},$ let $r_2=\frac{7}{8}.$ $B=\frac{5}{8}<\frac{1}{2}+(1-b_2)=R$
If $\frac{3}{4}< b_2,$ let $r_2 = \frac{3}{4}.$ $B=\frac{3}{4}<b_2=R$

The cases with $b_1>\frac{1}{2}$ are proven analogously to the cases $b_1<\frac{1}{2}.$ Red can always guarantee that $R>B,$ therefore they have a winning strategy.
Note that we never used the points $\{0,1\}$ in this strategy, so this proves that red also wins if the game is played on $(0,1).$

My own thoughts were leading this way. The first two moves in the game for any $m$ are special. Blue's first move is the only one that does not change how much territory either player owns, and Red's first move is the only one that increases the territory owned by the opponent. All other moves either increase the player's own territory, or decrease their opponent's territory, but not both. The fact that $m=1$ is a Blue win is likely an abberation due to the unique circumstances of those first moves, not an indication that Blue has an innate advantage.
